# Python weather detector

Tags: json, error-handling

I am getting this error for this python code to detect or tell the weather in any city.

```
Enter a city: London
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\UNITY INTERN EVUT21\PythonProjects\pro1\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    weather_data = requests.get(base_url).json()
```

Here's the code:

```py
import requests 
from pprint import pprint
API_Keys = "secret"
city = input("Enter a city: ")
base_url = "http//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid="+API_Keys+"&q="+city
weather_data = requests.get(base_url).json()
pprint(weather_data)
```

Comment: Please read the documentation about what a good SO question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `http//api.openweathermap.org/...` is not valid. It should be `https://api.openweathermap.org/...`. Then you should also check the HTTP status code to make sure the request was successful.

Side note: When using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) your code will be much easier to read.

```py
import requests
API_Keys="secret"
city = input("Enter a city: ")
base_url = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid={API_Keys}&q={city}"
weather_response = requests.get(base_url)
if weather_response.status_code != 200:
    print(f"API request failed with status code {weather_response.status_code}")
    sys.exit(1)
parsed_json = weather_response.json()
```

Comment: No worries. By the way, next time you post a question, make sure to exclude your API keys. These should be kept secret, because others could potentially do harm in your name with it, it's like posting a password for your account online. I've removed them from the question and my answer :)

Comment: Another thing, you can mark an answer as [*accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) on StackOverflow if you feel the answer answers your question properly. Note, you should do that after considering all the answers you have gotten and pick the one that you think is the best.